# How to get parse.com working with the Flash Player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parse-platform

I've already used Parse.com with iOS and it's great, I'm also aware of the 3rd party actionscript/parse API, but that only works with AIR.

So my question is, how would I get the parse API working with a Flash web game? (i'e with the Flash player).

There's also a PHP Parse API which uses the Parse.com REST API I believe, would that be an option? or is there just something about the Flash player that won't work with the parse API?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about Flash that wouldn't work with the parse rest api.  If you can call the api from php you can call it from as3, c++, .net, or klingon.

Comment: This is the link to the 3rd party API https://github.com/parkerkrhoyt/Parse if you scroll down you should see where it says "Note that Flash Player does not allow modifications to the HTTP Authentication header, so this library works only using AIR.  I have tested it both on the desktop and for mobile applications. "

Comment: Ok so you're saying just use the PHP API from the Flash player then?

Comment: you can do auth headers with flash, just not with standard components.  Phil, if you need a class that does this, I will email you one I wrote.  Does custom headers, full restful put, delete etc,

Comment: Thanks, still confused though :), so your class works from the Flash player to the Parse.com REST API directly? or does it go via PHP?

Comment: here is a link to an open source class library that does stuff similar to what I am doing [RestHTTPService](http://code.google.com/p/resthttpservice/) it says it replaces the Flex HTTPService component, but I looked at it's code and it is written in pure as3 and is not flex dependent that I can see.

Comment: Liar! I tried calling it with Klingon and it didn't work -_-
I am thinking about taking back my upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

flash player cant use header unless you are POST and with sending data/variable, if you want to use parse in flash player you need a custom flash.net.URLLoader, here is the one that i have found, but for some reason it doesn't work at new version of flash player, here is the link http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/2006/03/03/http-authentication-for-httpget-requests-using-actionscript-3/

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to perform a working REST call to Parse server

```
public function runParseCloudFunction(cloudFunctionName:String):void 
        {             
            if (parseRequestor != null){
                return;
            }           

            //Create the HTTP request object 
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/" + cloudFunctionName ); 
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

            // Create Parse headers
            var headerAppID:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", MY_PARSE_APP_ID);
            var headerRestKey:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", MY_PARSE_REST_KEY);
            var headerContentType:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.requestHeaders.push(headerAppID);
            request.requestHeaders.push(headerRestKey);
            request.requestHeaders.push(headerContentType);

            //Add the URL variables, json encoded format (OPTIONAL)             
            request.data = '{"param1":"sample1","param2":"sample2","param3":"sample3"}';

            //Initiate the transaction 
            parseRequestor = new URLLoader(); 
            //requestor.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;          
            parseRequestor.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, callParseCloudFunctionCompleted ); 
            parseRequestor.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, callParseCloudFunctionError ); 
            parseRequestor.addEventListener( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, callParseCloudFunctionError ); 
            parseRequestor.addEventListener( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, callParseStatusHandler);
            parseRequestor.load( request ); 
        }
```

Tested with cloud parse api version **1.3.2**

Hope it helps!!